# error when trying to deploy react app to heroku

Tags: reactjs, heroku

when im trying to deploy my react app to heroku using github,
i get this errors and the app crashes.
working just fine on my localhost.
maybe someone has an idea what's wrong?
thanks alot !

```
2022-03-12T17:31:37.981845+00:00 heroku[run.2815]: Awaiting client
2022-03-12T17:31:37.999825+00:00 heroku[run.2815]: Starting process with command `rails console`
2022-03-12T17:31:38.069927+00:00 heroku[run.2815]: State changed from starting to up
2022-03-12T17:31:41.361855+00:00 heroku[run.2815]: Process exited with status 127
2022-03-12T17:31:41.473733+00:00 heroku[run.2815]: State changed from up to complete
2022-03-12T17:31:47.014156+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=crud-react-project.herokuapp.com request_id=7d62d4a6-2b86-4616-90d2-03ab767f2430 fwd="46.121.142.152" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https 
2022-03-12T17:31:47.259249+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=crud-react-project.herokuapp.com request_id=6622728a-a7eb-4271-970d-62b0c8e4cdbf fwd="46.121.142.152" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-03-12T17:33:29.304499+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=crud-react-project.herokuapp.com request_id=f00e14a6-6ed5-4e9d-8f29-5b3bc8559258 fwd="46.121.142.152" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https 
2022-03-12T17:33:29.592482+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=crud-react-project.herokuapp.com request_id=3a4cf525-d4e7-4267-b394-ee6299bf00b2 fwd="46.121.142.152" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-03-12T17:33:50.171969+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=crud-react-project.herokuapp.com request_id=40c4db17-7fb5-4fe8-869f-9f32c52945c4 fwd="46.121.142.152" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https 
2022-03-12T17:33:50.578246+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=crud-react-project.herokuapp.com request_id=d670794d-3062-46c0-b425-55e50a6c0ba6 fwd="46.121.142.152" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Comment: what is the command you have used to deploy the app (maybe in package.json; some build script) ?

Comment: "scripts": {
    "predeploy": "npm run build",
    "deploy": "gh-pages -d build",
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },